# How do you get the value of the currently selected option in a bootstrap 5 multi-select dropdown list

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, bootstrap-5

I've tried the following but they return the list of select values not the option that fired the onchange event.  How can I identify the selected option's value that fired the event?

```
$('#ddlCostCenters').on('change', function (e) {
   alert($(this).val());           //returns the list of selected
   alert(e.currentTarget.value);   //returns the list of selected
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function signature is the key. Parm names element and checked provide what is needed.

The following is a great source for learning how bootstrap works
[Bootstrap multi-select](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#further-examples)

```
onChange: function(element, checked) {
    if (checked === true) {
        if ($('#ddl1 option[value=' + element.val() + ']:selected').length > 0){
            alert("Options are mutually exclusive. Selection canceled...");
            $('#ddl1').multiselect('deselect', element.val());
        }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a work demo to get the value of the currently selected option , you can refer to it.

Brand:

```
 public class Brand
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

VehicleVM:

```
public class VehicleVM
    {             
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> BrandList { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var brands = new List<Brand>();
            brands.Add(new Brand() { Id = 1, Name = " brand1" });
            brands.Add(new Brand() { Id = 2, Name = "brand2" });
            var BrandList = new SelectList(brands, "Name", "Name");
            var model = new VehicleVM();
            model.BrandList=BrandList;  
            return View(model);
        }
```

Index view:

```
@model VehicleVM
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.BrandList, new MultiSelectList( Model.BrandList, "Value", "Text"), new {  multiple = "multiple",id = "ddlCostCenters" })

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $('#ddlCostCenters').on('change', function (e) {
        alert($(this).val());           //returns the list of selected           
    });
</script>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but if you select more then one option it returns the values of all selected items.

Comment: @JohnButler ,Yes, yon don't want return the values of all selected items when you select more then one option ?